# Is the genitive understandable when there's no article nor adjective?

Tags: word-usage, declension

I see this in a job advert:

> Gutes Verständnis von Netzwerken, Firewalls, Routern und Security

However if we used the genitive, that would have to be:

> Gutes Verständnis Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security

Now I think that it can still be understood (if nothing else, by elimination), but my question is: is it better (where "better" means "clearer" or "more elegant"), in those cases where nothing but the undeclined noun is left, to stick to the "von + dative" form? Or is it equally understandable and nice for a native reader/listener?

Comment: As Christian pointed out, the second form is illegal without an article, but the only possible article "der" changes the meaning drastically. (IMHO, see my comment)

Comment: actually der is not the only possible article. one could also use *"für"*

Comment: @Vogel612 Verständnis für Personen, Umstände, etc. ok, but "Verständnis für Firewalls"? Not really, this would back-translate to "emphaty for firewalls". As in the other case, the meaning is changed.

Comment: @ingo in diesem fall ist das rein technische Verständnis gemeint. hat mit Empathie überhaupt gar nichts zu tun. --> die Übersetzung wäre: *"understanding for [...]"*

Comment: @Vogel612 zugegeben, ich habe ein wenig übertrieben, aber dennoch geht "für" meiner Meinung nach hier zwar grammatisch, verfälscht aber, was OP sagen wollte. Können wir nicht einfach sagen, daß die Version mit "von" die bessere und üblichere ist?

Comment: @Ingo ich halte das für ein Gerücht, wobei ich dir bei einem subtilen Bedeutungsunterschied zustimmen  muss

Comment: @Vogel612 Seit wann ist "für" denn ein Artikel?

Comment: @Ingo, Du hast nicht übertrieben.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zusätzlich zu bereits vorhandenen Antworten, ist es *immer* verständlich, wenn statt einem Artikel ein Adjektiv steht. Bsp:

> Gutes Verständnis *moderner* Netzwerke.

Obwohl in kurzen Anzeigen der Ausdruck *„Gutes Verständnis Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security“* gewissermaßen zu verstehen ist, ist dieser Satzbau ungrammatisch und folglich einfach falsch.

Wenn da kein Adjektiv (z.B. „Gutes Verständnis *drahtloser* Netzwerke“),
kein Pronomen (z.B. „Gutes Verständnis *meines* Netzwerks“) oder
kein Artikel (z.B. „Gutes Verständnis *der* Netzwerke“) steht,
braucht der Satz die Präposition *von*.

Answer (score 4):

I would tolerate the second variant mentioned in the OP

> Gutes Verständnis Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security

maybe if and *only* if in an advert, knowing that they want to save words (= $$ / €€) and used the terms "Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security" as an enumeration — loosely coupled to "Verständnis" without any grammatical context. It sounds a bit cheap though.

Usage of genitive without article is wrong. Fortunately, in the example everything is either plural or foreign words, so you can't detect a (false) genitive here anyway.

Usage of the "bestimmter Artikel" plus genitive here would be wrong unless you refer to a particular (kind of) networks etc. that you specified earlier (or later) — e.g. by mentioning a particular brand name.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the *correct* genitive would be:

```
Gutes Verständnis der Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security
```

To me as a native German the genitive construction sounds more demanding like you have to know *all* existing types of networks etc. Or it might refer to certain types of networks that have been mentioned in the ad before.

Whereas the construction with `von` sounds like you have to know how networks work.

Comment: Well, the correct genitive /if/ the nouns were qualified with an article (and thus "von den Netzwerken" etc.). Here however the meaning is "networks in general", "firewalls in general" etc. To my (rigorously non-native) understanding, saying "der Netzwerke" restricts the intended meaning to a (perhaps wide) specific category or type of networks. Is that really the case in German? (perhaps I should open a separate question for this)

Comment: The genitive may be grammatically correct, but it is worth pointing out that it doesn't make sense in this case, because it implies some specific networks, routers etc. have to be know, like in "Gutes Verständnis der Router in Werk 3." whereas with the "von" only know-how about routers in general is asked for.

Comment: @Ingo: does that imply that a genitive construction would in this case be impossible?

Comment: @karoshi I'd say so, given that you want to say something like "Gutes Verständnis von Routern" or "Umfangreiches Wissen über Netzwerke". It's too general. However, you **could** say "Gutes Verständnis des SMTP Protokolls." It's something definite, you know, therefore the definite article is appropriate here.

Comment: @karoshi You could also say "Gutes Verständnis einiger/aller/mancher/seltener/gebräuchlicher/aktueller Netzwerke." if you insist on the Genitive.

Comment: I'm not insisting :-), I was just trying to understand.

Comment: @karoshi No problem, very welcome. As you see in the discussions, a small word can change the meaning drastically. Or not so drastically, according to others. So it's well worth discussing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say, that "Gutes Verständnis Netzwerke, Firewalls, Router und Security" is illegal here, because this is part of an job advert. There are often  incomplete sentences used, for example in enumerations. The understanding for native speakers would be the same as in the original text.

Comment: To me it would be almost incomprehensible. Now, this may not matter in a job market, where thousands of jobless network specialists are roaming the AfA, but it *does* matter when you compete with your advertising against other employers.

Comment: This is *not* part of a job advert, the actual job advert uses the "von" form. I was just wondering if genitive could be used here.

Comment: @Karoshi, yes, that I understood. But I thought that you want to use it in the same context. And that was for me a job advert. Then it is possible.

Comment: @Ingo: Wo liegt für dich der Unterschied im Verständnis zwischen diesen beiden ersten Varianten? (Abgesehen davon, dass bei beiden nicht klar wäre, welche Kenntnisse nun genau gefordert werden. Aber das ist hier nicht die Frage.)

Comment: @Katja Wenn das geht, würde ich über das fehlende "von" oder sonst ein Füllwort "stolpern". Ich müßte quasi "zurücksetzen" und denken, ok, hier steht kein richtiger Satz, schaun wir mal, was es heißen könnte.

Comment: @Katja Im Prinzip ist das "Telegrammstil", wo man Wörter wegläßt, in der Hoffnung, daß der Leser sie aus dem Kontext rekonstruieren kann. Es könnte da auch stehen "Zertifizierung Cisco", und da es eine Jobausschreibung ist, könnte man annehmen, daß diese Zertifizierung erwünscht ist. (Oder ist sie gar Bedingung?)

Comment: Das wird auch nicht deutlich mit dem Original, da es sich hier nur um einen Ausschnitt handelt, und wir den Rest von dem Text nicht kennen. Das Wort "von" macht hier dann letztlich keinen Unterschied mehr. Ob Bedingung oder Wunsch, müsste dann bereits vorab genannt worden sein, bspw.: "Erforderlich sind folgende Qualifikationen/Kenntnisse:" und dann eine Aufzählung in Stichpunkten. Und Stichpunkte werden üblicherweise nicht in ganzen Sätzen formuliert.

Comment: Genau, @Katja, so in der Art hatte ich es auch gedacht, als Stichpunkt (dann entsprechend abgesetzt) macht es mehr Sinn.